# How to remove index.php from baseUrl Yii

Tags: php, yii, url-rewriting

I have removed the index.php from the URL using the .htaccess also the controller name "site" using the URL Management present in main/config.php.

But when I `echo` the base `url(Yii::app()->baseUrl);` it prints me with the `index.php`. Could anyone advise me on how to remove it?

Comment: do you actually see `index.php` in the uri? if not, why does it disturb you that `url(Yii::app()->baseUrl)` returns `index.php`? if you want to check against what page you're at, you should rather check against the controller action `Yii::app()->controller->action->id`

Comment: when i do some redirect as for eg:
<a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>">Home</a> 
This returns me to mywebsite.com/index.php rather than mywebsite.com

Comment: Okay i got it actually it was homeUrl that turns me to mywebsite.com/index.php, where as baseUrl works fine .

Answer (score 1):

In the UrlManager set the `showScriptName` to false and `urlFormat` to path:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    [...]
)
```